# Python : count the number of changes of numbers

Tags: python

I know the title is confusing, I didn't know how else to explain it, so here is a better explanation:

I have a file where each line is written as followed:

> a,b,c

where a,b and c are numbers. Here, the numbers a are irrelevant. Here, b are supposed to be some kind of coordinates and c is a group number.

For each c, I need to find the counts of each kind of movements the group made.

For example, let's say my file is something like that:

```
23,20,789
25,7,789
29,7,789
32,20,789
0,2,870
3,40,870
```

So I need to count how many times the group 789 moves from 1 to 1, 1 to 2, ..., 7 to 7, ... 20 to 7, 20 to 8, ... and so on until 117 to 117.
And do this for each group.

Of course, there will be lots of zeros which is ok.
So for example here I should find:

For the group 789: 1 move from 20 to 7, 1 move from 7 to 7, 1 move from 7 to 20 and 0 move for all the other combination of movement.

For the group 870: 1 move from 2 to 40 and 0 for all the other combination of movement.

I hope it was clear.

I know I should put what I began to do, but that is my problem. I really don't know where to start. I mean I know how to count how many times a digit or a string appears in a text, but to count the changes and especially by groups, I have no clue where to start.

I hope you can help me at least start.

Thank you

EDIT: Here is what I have for now thanks to @Tojrah

```
f1=open("My_file_where_the_coordinates_for_one_group_are_all_in_one_line.txt","r")
f2=open("File_of_counts.txt","a")
line=f1.readline()
s=line.split()
count=0

for i in range (0,len(s)-1):
    for j in range (1,len(s)-1):
        if s[j]==s[i] and s[j+1]==s[i+1]:
            count+=1
    f2.write("from {} to {} , result= {}\n".format(s[i], s[i+1], count))
    count=0
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

But you can surely guess, here are the result partially shown:

```
from 20 to 7 , result= 5
from 7 to 7 , result= 9
from 7 to 20 , result= 6
from 20 to 20 , result= 28242
from 20 to 20 , result= 28242
from 20 to 20 , result= 28242
from 20 to 20 , result= 28242
```

You can see that the counts are good but it counts the same movements several time. How to stop it from counting the movements already counted?

EDIT 2:
Here are the changes I made to @Tojrah 's code:

```
for i in range (1,118):
for j in range (1,118):
    count=0
    for k in range (0, len(s)-1):
        if (str(i)==s[k] and str(j)==s[k+1]):
            count+=1
    f.write("from {} to {} , result= {}\n".format(i, j, count))
    count=0
```

Now it works perfectly fine.
Thanks again to @Tojrah for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append all the values at the second place (number b) in a list for a particular group (say, 789). Then just iterate over the list using nested loops and you can get all the moves you want. Hope this is what you want. 
Code:

```
for i in range(1,118):
    for j in range(1,118):
         count=0
         for p in range(len(list)-1):
             if(list[p]==i and list[p+1]==j):
                 count+=1
         if(count!=0):
             #print/write Statement here
```

If you're still stuck I can help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try that.

Comment: I added some code from what you said, and I edited my first post with it. If you could tell me what I'm doing wrong I would be so grateful. Thanks

Comment: Can you show me what is s. I mean how are you splitting the line (what is the separator for splitting?). Also ,readline should return only one line

Comment: f1 is my file of coordinates written like that: `20 20 7 7 8 10 20 20` in one line. s is just a list of the coordinates, meaning `[20,20,7,7,8,10,20,20]`. The separator is a space.

Comment: Okay,got it. (Sorry as I didn't see the file name F1!). So actually to avoid repetition I suggest instead of checking for pairs in the list itself,you should use nested loops ,each one going from 1 to 117 as you said,and check the number of pairs, `i,j` in the list(a third loop would iterate over list,so nesting thrice).This would be simplest way to handle this problem and avoid repetition!(you can avoid printing those  with zero counts).

Comment: Do you mean something like that: 
`for i in range (1,118):
    for j in range (1,118):
        for k in range (1, len(s)-1):
            if s[k]==i and s[k+1]==j:
                count+=1
            f.write("from {} to {} , result= {}\n".format(i, j, count))
    count=0` Sorry I don't know how to indent in te comments

Comment: Yes , that's what I am saying. So is this fine?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It writes de different steps, but the count is always 0

Comment: I'm very thankful for the time you are taking to help me. But it still doesn't work. I don't see where the problem could be. With your code, there is nothing written, I guess it's because everything is at 0 whereas it shouldn't be

Comment: I made a few changes to your code, and now it works. You can see it in the EDIT2. Thanks again for your help