# Counting the transitions from specific variable to anoter one

Tags: python

My problem is very similar to this post:
[Python : count the number of changes of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55238486/python-count-the-number-of-changes-of-numbers/55238952?noredirect=1#comment97248882_55238952)

But since I cannot comment yet, I would like to know if there is a faster way?

My code is significantly the same as in the link, but the ranges of i and j are way much bigger (around one million in total) , meaning that it takes a significantly larger time to count (more than a day!)

Comment: Python is not really the language of choice for high-performance computing.

Comment: I can see why. But it's the language I'm asked to use, I have no other choice.

Comment: If your `i` and `j` values have a range of about 1 million, then there are about 1e12 possible transitions... just having those written to a file would take terabytes... is that really what you are trying to compute?

Comment: If it takes more than a day, just start the job on Friday afternoon, and have the results first thing on Monday. You're not mentioning how often you need to run the same program, or any indication how fast you'd like it to be.

Comment: It would be good if you include the actual code you have, and possibly some sample data, in your question. Linking to another question is fine, but it's annoying to go back and forth: a single, complete question, would be nicer. (The linked question is also a rather lengthy read; a summarized version would be nice.)

Comment: Additionally, if you have working code but want to improve it, you should write it up as a complete example and take it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com . This site is more for nonworking code and how-to, that site is for decreasing runtimes, etc

Comment: @jdehesa i and j are not 1 million each, I wanted to say that there are about 1 million transitions

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you, I will see there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most definitely a better idea to save all the transition counts to a data structure instead of counting the appearances of each individual transition. It could be something like this:

```py
def count_transitions(numbers):
    n = max(numbers)
    transitions = [[0] * (n + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)]
    for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
        n1 = numbers[i]
        n2 = numbers[i + 1]
        transitions[n1][n2] += 1
    return transitions
```

An example of how you could use it:

```py
test_data = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1]
test_result = count_transitions(test_data)
for i, row in enumerate(test_result):
    for j, count in enumerate(row):
        print(f'{i} -> {j}: {count}')
```

Output:

```
0 -> 0: 0
0 -> 1: 3
0 -> 2: 1
1 -> 0: 2
1 -> 1: 1
1 -> 2: 1
2 -> 0: 2
2 -> 1: 0
2 -> 2: 0
```

Now, another matter is making this fast. This algorithm should already be much faster, because it has linear complexity instead of cubic, but we can use a couple of tools to make it still better. For example, using NumPy you could do it just like this:

```py
import numpy as np

def count_transitions_np(numbers):
    numbers = np.asarray(numbers)
    n = numbers.max()
    transitions = np.zeros((n + 1, n + 1), dtype=np.int32)
    np.add.at(transitions, (numbers[:-1], numbers[1:]), 1)
    return transitions
```

Or you can use Numba with something like this:

```py
@nb.njit
def count_transitions_nb(numbers):
    n = 0
    for num in numbers:
        n = max(num, n)
    transitions = np.zeros((n + 1, n + 1), dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
        n1 = numbers[i]
        n2 = numbers[i + 1]
        transitions[n1, n2] += 1
    return transitions
```

Finally, yet another option is to build a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) with SciPy. Note this is not the same as a dense matrix, but you may be able to work with it too.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

def count_transitions_sp(numbers):
    numbers = np.asarray(numbers)
    n = numbers.max()
    v = np.ones(len(numbers) - 1, dtype=np.int32)
    return scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((v, (numbers[:-1], numbers[1:])), (n + 1, n + 1))
```

And now a small benchmark:

```py
import random

# Generate input data
random.seed(100)
numbers = [random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(1000000)]

# Check results are correct
result1 = count_transitions(numbers)
result2 = count_transitions_np(numbers).tolist()
result3 = count_transitions_nb(numbers).tolist()
result4 = count_transitions_sp(numbers).todense().tolist()
print(result1 == result2)
# True
print(result1 == result3)
# True
print(result1 == result4)
# True

# NumPy version of data for NumPy, Numba and SciPy
numbers_np = np.asarray(numbers)
# Time it with IPython
%timeit count_transitions(numbers)
# 178 ms ± 633 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit count_transitions_np(numbers_np)
# 80.7 ms ± 663 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit count_transitions_nb(numbers_np)
# 5.36 ms ± 240 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit count_transitions_sp(numbers_np)
# 4.05 ms ± 47.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you see, Numba can be really fast, and sparse matrices are quick to build too if you can use them.

Comment: Thanks for your help